# Extract bands as individual layers from a multilayered tiff file

Tags: r, raster, tiff, geotiff

I have a tiff file which contains 6 bands [Data link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nQ5Tgjp304-x-5ut9IfAdEGDcgLs4H1_/view?usp=sharing), I used all methods to extract [See here][2] [see here 2][3] all 6 bands as individual layers but unable to extract them as individual files.

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)
r <- raster("E:/TRY/bands.tif")
writeRaster(r, paste0(names(r),".tif"), bylayer=TRUE, format="GTiff")
```

I get just one tif file and the file doesn't have any information whatsoever like what it is.

Appreciate any help

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the function `raster::stack`. This will read all the layers.

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)
s1 <- stack("~/Downloads/bands.tif")
writeRaster(s1, paste0(names(s1),".tif"), bylayer=TRUE, format="GTiff")
```

Comment: In this case (a single file), `brick` would be more efficient than `stack`

Comment: Thank you, guys !!! both functions work ```stack``` & ```brick```

Comment: As @RobertHijmans said, `brick` is more efficient in this case. He's the author of the `raster` package so he'll know.